# Unauthorized User Vuejs Token

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, access-token, laravel-5.4, vue-resource

I am using vuejs as my front end and Laravel 5.4 as backend. I am using custom authoriziation at frontend and laravel passport for backend. I am facing a very abnormal behaviour.. When i authenticate a user via token and save that token in my localStorage. just after that i fire another method to get authentciated User. I am setting the headers properly with authorization token but it says unauthorized user. When i refresh it sends the same request but now it gets the user properly.. I am not being able to figure out what could be the issue

this is my main.js file

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Router from './routes.js'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import { store } from './store';
import App from './App.vue'
import Auth from './packages/auth/Auth'
import _ from 'lodash'

Vue.use(Auth);
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(ElementUI);
Vue.use(_);

//Vue.http.options.root = 'http://backend.finlinkpro.com/public';
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://localhost/FinLinkWeb/BackEnd/public';
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getToken();
```

This is the login file which sends the request

```
   loginUser: function () {

            this.loginbtn = !this.loginbtn;
            var data = {
                client_id: '2',
                //yGeTHPRWObsjdQeYXMx4tUG84TUqUTyTvd9UnR03 Dev Site Client
                //jB0mH8Tf1SK2MTxXzjcBWiTg7iWgHcybr1nvyDBI Local Client
                client_secret: 'jB0mH8Tf1SK2MTxXzjcBWiTg7iWgHcybr1nvyDBI',
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: this.loginForm.email,
                password: this.loginForm.password,

            };
            let self = this;
            this.$http.post('oauth/token', data).then(function (response) {
                this.$auth.setToken(response.body.access_token, response.body.expires_in + Date.now());

                self.$http.post('api/user' , {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer '+ response.body.access_token
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                });
                self.$router.push('/profile/first_login');
                self.loginbtn = !this.loginbtn;


            }).catch(function () {
                self.loginbtn = !this.loginbtn;
            });

        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but the problem seems to be with the crsfToken, check if you're using a dead one.

Comment: no that is not the issue here.. issue is that the access token is rejected. or maybe it isnt even sent.

Comment: you said it's working when you refresh so the token isn't getting rejected.
to get more insight check the difference with the code that runs when you refresh the page, and try to remove the auth middleware from 'api/user' and print some debugging messages to check if the headers are being sent.
I hope this helps.